# SMOTE initialisation expects n_neighbors <= n_samples, but n_samples < n_neighbors

Tags: scikit-learn, knn, tf-idf, oversampling, imblearn

I have already pre-cleaned the data, and below shows the format of the top 4 rows:

```
     [IN] df.head()

    [OUT]   Year    cleaned
         0  1909    acquaint hous receiv follow letter clerk crown...
         1  1909    ask secretari state war whether issu statement...
         2  1909    i beg present petit sign upward motor car driv...
         3  1909    i desir ask secretari state war second lieuten...
         4  1909    ask secretari state war whether would introduc...
```

I have called train_test_split() as follows:

```
     [IN] X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['cleaned'], df['Year'], random_state=2)
   [Note*] `X_train` and `y_train` are now Pandas.core.series.Series of shape (1785,) and `X_test` and `y_test` are also Pandas.core.series.Series of shape (595,)
```

I have then vectorized the X training and testing data using the following TfidfVectorizer and fit/transform procedures:

```
     [IN] v = TfidfVectorizer(decode_error='replace', encoding='utf-8', stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1, 1), sublinear_tf=True)
          X_train = v.fit_transform(X_train)
          X_test = v.transform(X_test)
```

I'm now at the stage where I would normally apply a classifier, etc (if this were a balanced set of data). However, I initialize imblearn's [SMOTE()](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) class (to perform over-sampling)...

```
     [IN] smote_pipeline = make_pipeline_imb(SMOTE(), classifier(random_state=42))
          smote_model = smote_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
          smote_prediction = smote_model.predict(X_test)
```

... but this results in:

```
     [OUT] ValueError: "Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples, but n_samples = 5, n_neighbors = 6.
```

I've attempted to whittle down the number of n_neighbors but to no avail, any tips or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT:**

[Full Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVP0G.png)

The dataset/dataframe (`df`) contains 2380 rows across two columns, as shown in `df.head()` above. `X_train` contains 1785 of these rows in the format of a list of strings (`df['cleaned']`) and `y_train` also contains 1785 rows in the format of strings (`df['Year']`).

Post-vectorization using `TfidfVectorizer()`: `X_train` and `X_test` are converted from `pandas.core.series.Series` of shape '(1785,)' and '(595,)' respectively, to `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` of shape '(1785, 126459)' and '(595, 126459)' respectively.

As for the number of classes: using `Counter()`, I've calculated that there are 199 classes (Years), each instance of a class is attached to one element of aforementioned `df['cleaned']` data which contains a list of strings extracted from a textual corpus.

The objective of this process is to automatically determine/guess the year, decade or century (any degree of classification will do!) of input textual data based on vocabularly present.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it? I guess you need more samples (rows) in your `X_train`

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of error.

Comment: Also please tell us your class imbalance. How many classes and how many samples in each class?

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone, I've done my best to address your questions in my edit to the original post. Please let me know if there's anything I could correct at all!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since there are approximately 200 classes and 1800 samples in the training set, you have on average 9 samples per class. The reason for the error message is that a) probably the data are not perfectly balanced and there are classes with less than 6 samples and b) the number of neighbors is 6. A few solutions for your problem:

1. Calculate the minimum number of samples (n_samples) among the 199 classes and select `n_neighbors` parameter of SMOTE class less or equal to n_samples.
2. Exclude from oversampling the classes with n_samples < n_neighbors using the `ratio` parameter of `SMOTE` class.
3. Use `RandomOverSampler` class which does not have a similar restriction.
4. Combine 3 and 4 solutions: Create a pipeline that is using `SMOTE` and `RandomOversampler` in a way that satisfies the condition n_neighbors <= n_samples for smoted classes and uses random oversampling when the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what about reducing the number of classes to e.g. decades (for prediction alone) instead of individual years? I'll crack on with your suggestions in the meantime!

Comment: I was unable to investigate (1) and (2) as some classes only possess one sample. However, I was able to successfully pipeline RandomOverSampler (and/or a FakeSampler Class), followed by SMOTE and the Classifier as shown: `make_pipeline(sampler, SMOTE(), clf)`. I'll proceed with this and see what I can do with it! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Dbercules: hi, can you please guide me, how did you do make the pipeline? I tried 

`sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)`

`rm = RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)`

`my_pipe = make_pipeline(sm, rm)`

`X_res, Y_res = my_pipe.fit_resample(X, y)`

But got the error, same as the title question

Answer (score 6):

Try to do the below code for SMOTE

`oversampler=SMOTE(kind='regular',k_neighbors=2)`

This worked for me.

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kind'
`

Answer (score 3):

**WHY IT OCCURS:**

In my case it was occurring because i had as few samples as 1 for some of the values/categories. Since SMOTE is based on KNN concept, it's not possible to apply SMOTE on 1 sampled values.

**HOW I SOLVED IT:**

> Since those 1 sampled values/categories were equivalent to outliers, i removed them from the dataset and then applied SMOTE and it worked.

> Also try decreasing the `k_neighbors` parameter to make it work

```py
xr, yr = SMOTE(k_neighbors=3).fit_resample(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's possible to use the code:

> sampler = SMOTE(ratio={1: 1927, 0: 300},random_state=0)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue following number 1 of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418705/6663387) answer.

```
from collections import Counter

Count(df) # get the classes

# drop the classes with 1 as their value because it's lower than k_neighbors which has 2 as minimum value in my case

X_res, y_res = SMOTE(k_neighbors = 2).fit_resample(X, y)
```