# How can we cluster average vectors in Python

Tags: python, nlp, classification, cluster-analysis, word2vec

I have a sentence and a corresponding averaged vector for that sentence. The dataset looks like this:

```
['there are two injuries one is previous']  -0.003632369
['I have motion with mucus from morning']   -0.000631669
['she will be fine with the meds?']     0.010474829
['can you please suggest some good diet']   0.008024994
```

I have around 100K rows. I want to cluster similar sentences together. Any idea on how this can be done. I tried different clustering algos from sklearn but getting similar error like "ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples,  but n_samples = 1, n_neighbors = 2"

Adding code sample:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'Documents/clusters.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1]
X = X.values.reshape(1, -1)

from sklearn.cluster import OPTICS
db = OPTICS(eps=3, min_samples=0).fit(X)
```

Comment: can you share your code implementation? There should be a bug in your code

Comment: Added the code sample. can you please check

Comment: By running these two lines `X = dataset.iloc[:, 1];
X = X.values.reshape(1, -1)` at the end you will have only one element with multiple fields. And Clustering algorithm can't work on one item. Can you check the shape of the X before executing `fit` part.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395939/smote-initialisation-expects-n-neighbors-n-samples-but-n-samples-n-neighbo) can help.

Comment: @CenkBircanoglu I printed the shape before fit part. It reads : (1, 72610).. 72610 actually the number of rows of sentences. Any idea from this part?

Comment: Can you use this one `X = X.values.reshape(-1, 1)` instead of `X = X.values.reshape(1, -1)` and try again

Comment: I tweaked the k means application and it is working now without changing the reshape part. kmeans.labels_ is giving me the groups. Thanks a lot for your help :)